# How to use a compare filter with an oracle date column

Tags: java, oracle, filter, vaadin, vaadin7

### Info and question

I wanna create (oracle sql) `ONE_DATE > to_date('31-12-2009', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`
with a [SQLContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/SQLContainer.html) [filter](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Container.Filter.html).

What do the arguments have to be for the ["Greater" filter](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/filter/Compare.Greater.html)?

```
new Greater("ONE_DATE", ???????)
```

---

### Common oracle approach

This is my code so far:

```
        Calendar c_from = new GregorianCalendar(2009, 11, 31);

        Date d_from = new Date(c_from.getTimeInMillis());

        currentFilter = new Greater("ONE_DATE", d_from);
```

However, this doesn't throw an exception nor provides any results =) (the data container is simply empty).

### Timestamp approach

> Have you tried passing Timestamp like `new Timestamp(d_from.getTime())`

Approach as suggested by Knu8:

```
        Calendar c_from = new GregorianCalendar(2009, 11, 31);

        Date d_from = new Date(c_from.getTimeInMillis());

        currentFilter = new Greater("ONE_DATE", new Timestamp(d_from.getTime()));
```

Same result: No exception but neither a single item in the container.

Comment: Similar filter is explained in this page [link](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1607492/1611710)

Comment: Have you tried passing Timestamp like `new Timestamp(d_from.getTime())` instead of date object as shown in the link above.

Comment: @Knu8 Thanks :) Edited my answer.